# Counting duplicate elements in prolog

Tags: prolog

i'm having problems with this subject in Prolog.
The thing is that I want to count the number of repeated elements appearing in a list,
and I also want to fill, in another list with 1, for each appearance of duplicated elements and a 0 if is not duplicated, e.g.

I have a list like this: [420,325,420,582,135,430,582], and the result should be [1,0,1,1,0,0,1].

I've tried some code snippets and it's driving me nuts.

The last code i've tried is:

```
count_duplicates([],[]).
count_duplicates([Head|Tail],[1|LS]):-
    member(Head,Tail),
    count_duplicates([Tail|Head],LS).

count_duplicates([Head|Tail],[0|LS]):-
    \+ member(Head,Tail),
    count_duplicates([Tail|Head],LS).
```

this predicate receive a list and have to generate the result list

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the input list contain 0s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
count_duplicate(In, Out) :-
    maplist(test(In), In, Out).


test(Src, Elem, 1) :-
    select(Elem, Src, Result),
    member(Elem, Result).

test(_Src, _Elem, 0).
```

**EDIT** Without maplist, you can do

```
count_duplicate(In, Out) :-
    test(In, In, Out).

test(_, [], []).

test(In, [Elem | T], [R0 | R]) :-
    select(Elem, In, Rest),
    (   member(Elem, Rest) -> R0 = 1; R0 = 0),
    test(In, T, R).
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit your code?, I don't understand this part: maplist(test(In), In, Out), test is test/3, but your calling it with only one argument.

Comment: Yes, it works with SWI-Prolog. maplist applies each element of In and Out to **test(In)**. For the first element you get `test([420,325,420,582,135,430,582], 420, 1)`, because `select(420,  [420,325,420,582,135,430,582], Result)` unifies Result with  [325,420,582,135,430,582] and 420 is a member of Result, next you get `test([420,325,420,582,135,430,582], 325, 0)`  because 325 is alone in In, ...

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite using some of list processing builtins available:

```
count_duplicates(L, R) :-
    maplist(check(L), L, R).

check(L, E, C) :-
    aggregate(count, member(E, L), Occurs),
    ( Occurs > 1 -> C = 1 ; C = 0 ).
```

with that

```
?- count_duplicates([420,325,420,582,135,430,582],L).
L = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1].
```

About your code, I think it's simple to get termination:

```
count_duplicates([],[]).
count_duplicates([Head|Tail],[1|LS]):-
    member(Head,Tail),
    count_duplicates(Tail,LS).
count_duplicates([Head|Tail],[0|LS]):-
    \+ member(Head,Tail),
    count_duplicates(Tail,LS).
```

Note I corrected the recursive calls, and consider that could be done in a slightly more efficient way (both source and runtime) using the if .. then .. else .. construct.

```
count_duplicates([],[]).
count_duplicates([Head|Tail],[R|LS]):-
    ( member(Head,Tail) -> R = 1 ; R = 0 ),
    count_duplicates(Tail,LS).
```

it's cleaner, isn't it? member/2 it's called just once, that's a big gain,
and consider using [memberchk](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=memberchk/2)/2 instead of member/2.

But that code **fails** to tag as multiple the last occurrence.